# close modalvew controller and parentview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to open a modalview from a view like that,

```
SignupViewController *signUpView = [[SignupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignupViewController" bundle:nil];
[signUpView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
self.parentViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
self.parentViewController.view.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:.35 animations:^{self.parentViewController.view.alpha  = 1.0; self.parentViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);}];
[self presentModalViewController:signUpView animated:YES];
```

After login i am closing the modalview and redirecting to anther view, but the parentview is still there,

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
ToolsViewController *gototoolpage = [[ToolsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ToolsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gototoolpage animated:YES];
}
```

How to dismiss the parentview also. Any idea

Answer (score 0):

You code looks a little confused. What do you intend by references to parentViewController? Check the docs - it is the *containing* viewController, not the *previous* or *presenting* viewController. In a NavigationController context this would be the UINavigationController. In a modal view context there is no parentViewController, but there is a *presenting* ViewController. I am not sure what you intend by all of those calls to self.parentViewController.

In any case you should really be sending the dismiss request back to your presenting viewController via a delegate so that it is completely clear where the pushViewController message is being passed from and to.

In the header file of your signUpViewController declare a protocol:

```
@protocol SignUpViewControllerDelegate
- (void) dissmissSignUpVC;
@end
```

then in your presentingViewController, after

```
SignupViewController *signUpView = [[SignupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignupViewController" bundle:nil];
```

add

```
[signUpView setDelegate:self];
```

and implement the delegate method with the same code you now have in your completion block:

```
- (void) dissmissSignUpVC {

    ToolsViewController *gototoolpage = [[ToolsViewController alloc] 
            initWithNibName:@"ToolsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gototoolpage animated:YES];
```

}

In signUpView invoke the delegate's method to dismiss:

```
[[self delegate] dissmissSignUpVC];
```

Watch out for those stacked animations, I suspect that only the first will be performed (i.e. `gototollpage animated:YES` might as well be `gototoolpage animated:NO`)

Perhaps anyway you should reconsider your logic. I imagine the user might have a confusing experience if you do this under-the-hood manipulation of viewControllers. Better that there is a UI control for the user to navigate to toolsViewController so they understand where they are?